# Выборка из выборки

Tags: android, база-данных, android-studio, выборка

Есть вот такие фильтры (это не все):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне необходимо после их заполнения произвести выборку из БД (Это как фильтры в любом интернет-магазине).
Проблема в следующем: Я не знаю как сделать выборку после того, как пользователь заполнит ВСЕ карточки (Выберет Бренд, укажет стоимость, укажет Год и т.д). Вот так я делаю выборку на основе выбранного БРЕНДА:

```
package com.example.covenant.optimization;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;

import static com.example.covenant.optimization.FilterActivity.Acer;
import static com.example.covenant.optimization.FilterActivity.Archos;
import static com.example.covenant.optimization.FilterActivity.Asus;
import static com.example.covenant.optimization.FilterActivity.Digma;
import static com.example.covenant.optimization.FilterActivity.Ginzuu;
import static com.example.covenant.optimization.FilterActivity.Huawei;
import static com.example.covenant.optimization.FilterActivity.Lenovo;
import static com.example.covenant.optimization.FilterActivity.Prestigio;
import static com.example.covenant.optimization.FilterActivity.Samsung;
import static com.example.covenant.optimization.FilterActivity.cena;

public class FindModelsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static ListView lv_findModels;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_models);
        setTitle("Подходящие модели");

        lv_findModels = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_findModels);

        showFindModels();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Asus = "";
        Lenovo = "";
        Samsung = "";
        Huawei = "";
        Acer = "";
        Prestigio ="";
        Digma = "";
        Archos = "";
        Ginzuu = "";

        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    //==============================================================================

    public void showFindModels() {
        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.query(
        /*таблица*/                         "tablets",
        /*столбцы*/                         null,
        /*условия "WHERE"*/                 "Бренд = ? or Бренд = ? or Бренд = ? or Бренд = ? or Бренд = ? or Бренд = ? or Бренд = ? or Бренд = ? or Бренд = ?",
        /*массив аргументов для selection*/ new String[] {Asus, Lenovo, Samsung, Huawei, Acer, Prestigio, Digma, Archos, Ginzuu},
        /*группировка*/                     null,
        /*фильтр для групировки*/           null,
        /*сортировка*/                      null
        );

        String[] from = new String[]{cursor.getColumnName(1), cursor.getColumnName(3), cursor.getColumnName(2)};//массив столбцов, поля которых собираемся отображать
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.tvName, R.id.tvPrice, R.id.tvModel};                              //Массив View-компонентов для отображения этих стобцов
        SimpleCursorAdapter sCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_listview, cursor, from, to, 0);//Создал адаптер и настроил ему кастомный вид
        lv_findModels.setAdapter(sCursorAdapter);                                                   //Повесил адаптер
        dbHelper.close();                                                                           //Закрыл подключение к БД
    }
}
```

Но как теперь из выборки по БРЕНДУ убрать, к примеру, товары ниже n-ой стоимости? Получается нужна еще одна ВЫБОРКА, которая пройдется с новым фильтром по существующей ВЫБОРКЕ. 
Мне кажется я неправильно мыслю на счет того, как все это реализовать. Помогите советом дельным.

Comment: Вам непременно нужно получить знания по СУБД, для начала хорошо почитать Л.Бейли "Изучаем SQL". По вопросу, нельзя сделать выборку из выборки (по крайней мере в андроид Cursor), вам нужен сложный запрос по нескольким условиям. При изменении фильтров делать новый запрос. PS: запрос в вашем коде, это конечно "шедевр", напрашивается вывод, что вся структура БД у вас в корне неправильная

Comment: Pavlofff, на счёт шедевра - да, знаю. А на счёт сложного запроса по нескольким условиям - может у вас есть пример на примете?

Comment: Лучше всего вам сначала прочитать книгу (название выше) по этой дисциплине, чтобы иметь понимание того, что вам отвечают (хотя прочитав ее вы и сами составите такой простой запрос). Дело в том, что проблема глубже, чем "есть пример", так как залог правильной работы с реляционной БД - правильная структура этой БД, без этого примеры не имеют никакого смысла, а вообще, если вам решительно нравится пробиваться методом проб и ошибок, самостоятельно изобретая вещи, которые существуют 10-ки лет, то  в ответе вполне подходящий пример

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял проблему то вы не знаете как сформировать запрос к бд. Ниже приведен небольшой пример (написал в блокноте поэтому могут быть ошибки). В качестве аргумента в `getFilteredProducts` вы должны передать сформированный экземпляр `Product` который хотите выбрать с бд.

```
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "products";
private static final String BRAND_COLUMN = "brand";
private static final String PRICE_COLUMN = "price";

...

public List<Product> getFilteredProducts(Product findProduct){

    List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME
            + " WHERE (" + BRAND_COLUMN + " = " + findProduct.getBrand()
            + " AND " + PRICE_COLUMN + " = " + findProduct.getPrice() 
            + " AND " + ... + " = " + findProduct.getSomeParam() + ");";
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

    try {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            Product product = new Product();
            product.setBrand(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BRAND_COLUMN)));
            product.setPrice(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(PRICE_COLUMN)));
            ...
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return products;
}
```

Сделал пример всего с двумя столбцами, надеюсь смысл вы поймете. Больше информации об логических операторах в SQLite вы можете найти [здесь](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/and_or.php).